# Why doesn't changing a closure property to a function cause the same retain cycle?

Tags: swift, function, memory-management, closures, automatic-ref-counting

> A strong reference cycle can also occur if you assign a closure to a
>   property of a class instance, and the body of that closure captures
>   the instance.

If closures as properties can cause strong retain cycles, and functions are a type of closure according to the [Swift programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94):

> Global and nested functions, as introduced in Functions, are actually
>   special cases of closures

Why doesn't changing a closure property to an instance method cause the same retain cycle?

> Instance methods are functions that belong to instances of a
>   particular class, structure, or enumeration.

For example, as is, the code below does not deallocate the instance of HTMLElement, however, if I change `asHTML` to a function instead of a name for a closure expression, the `HTMLElement` is deallocated.

```
class HTMLElement {
    let name: String
    let text: String?
    lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        return "<\(self.name)>\(self.text ?? "")</\(self.name)>"
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }
    deinit {print("\(name) is being deinitialized")}
}

var headerTitle: HTMLElement? = HTMLElement(name: "h1", text: "Welcome")
print(headerTitle!.asHTML())
headerTitle = nil
```

Debugger:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

When changed to a function:

```
func asHTML() -> String {
    return "<\(self.name)>\(self.text ?? "")</\(self.name)>"
}
```

Debugger:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
h1 is being deinitialized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closure causes a retain cycle when you save it to an instance variable, so you have a strong reference to the closure, and then the closure has a strong reference to the object that holds it.

In your first example, your var asHTML is a closure saved to an instance variable in your `HTMLElement` class. That means that the `HTMLElement` instance keeps a strong reference to the closure.

Then in your closure you make reference to `self`. That means that the closure holds a strong reference to the object that's defining it (again, the `HTMLElement` instance.) You've created a retain cycle.

Now, if instead you have a function `asHTML()` that you call, you're not saving the function as an object somewhere. It's an instance method of the object. It has a reference to self because it is **PART** of self. Thus no retain cycle.

Comment: So when my method references self, ARC does not count this as a reference, but instead, the Swift compiler simply counts the method as a component of its object?

Comment: A closure is a first class object. It is an entity in its own right, separate from the object that saves it. An instance method is not a separate object. An instance method is code that belongs to the object.

Comment: Can you correct my understanding? A method is a function on a class, a function is a closure, a closure is a reference type.  Why is this instance method not a separate object?

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading Apple's documentation wrong: "Global and nested functions, as introduced in Functions, are actually special cases of closures".  (Please, and thank you).

Comment: Yes, functions/methods are special cases of closures (Except instance methods). Where are you capturing the function in your 2nd version though? (Answer: You're not. You're using an instance method, which is not a discrete object.) In order to create a retain cycle you need two discrete objects that hold strong references to each other.